# Encog SVM won't train

Tags: java, csv, svm, encog

I am trying to train a SVM to classify two spiral data.

My input is a 3 column CSV file, the first two columns are the (x, y)-coordinates of a point on a spiral (not normalised) and the third column is the spiral (class) that the point belongs to.

I first normalise the CSV file so that the first two columns are between 0 and 1 (third column remains unchanged).

Then I create and train an SVM as follows

```
    CSVNeuralDataSet trainingSet = new CSVNeuralDataSer(normaliseCSV("/path/to/data/file"), 2, 1, false);

SVM svm = new SVM(2, false);

final SVMSearchTrain train = new SVMSearchTrain(svm, trainingSet);

int epoch = 0;

do {
  train.iteration();
  System.out.println("Epoch $: " + epoch + " Error: " + train.getError());
  epoch++;
} while(train.getError() > 0.01);

train.finishTraining();
```

However, the do...while loop ends up being an infinite loop as the training error is around 0.4 and it never changes.

The data set contains around 200 samples and there are only two classes (0 and 1).

Can anyone tell me why this is failing?

EDIT: [Here is a pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/VhNspSvd) to roughly 10% of the training data.

Comment: Can you please share a fragment of normalized data?

Comment: Edited to add a pastebin link to sample data.

Answer (score 2):

Wonderful question. Your problem is that SVM can't built separation curve for spiral data. I propose you to try normalization trick, but normalize not according to X, Y coordinates as straight lines, but [switch](http://www.teacherschoice.com.au/maths_library/coordinates/polar_-_rectangular_conversion.htm) to [polar system of coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system). And consider probably Archimedean spiral, logarithmic spiral, etc. [image]. Please look at picture. Spiral data require from SVM to built some function which will separate data between Class 1 and Class 2, and I'm pretty sure that it is not easy task for SVM. But if you will find way to switch from spiral data representation to linear, then SVM will need to built separation between two curves, which is much easier.

Comment: Also please make sure, that Class 1 and class 2 doesn't intersect